# Lambda invocation on two SNS events at the sametime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a usecase where I need to read the two files which are in a different account, I will be receiving an SNS event with the filename and I need to create an EMR cluster from the Lambda only if two files are available in the other s3 bucket.

Currently I am writing dummy files to s3 bucket every time I receive a SNS event and then creating the EMR cluster only after ensuring that on the second SNS event that I have received, the first file is available in my accounts s3 bucket- This approach is working fine.

But I am unable to solve the issue of what really happens if we receive two files at the same time in the other s3 bucket and if we get two sns events around the same time, as each event thinks the other file hasn’t been arrived yet.

How would I solve this problem .

Comment: How do you correlate these two events? Let's say they happen 1 hour apart, how do you know that the 2nd event correlates to the event one hour ago?

Comment: @jarmod - I know the file patterns and based on the file patterns currently I am correlating the events as I am storing dummy filenames in my account’s s3 bucket- After I have created the EMR cluster after I have sent both the file names to it for processing. I am deleting the dummy files that I have created  in my s3 bucket.